# Since $(\frac{1}{2})!=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$, what is $(\frac{1}{4})!$

Tags: factorial

I once heard on the internet that $(\frac{1}{2})!=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ so now, I'm wondering what $(\frac{1}{4})!$ is equal to.

---

My attempt:

Since $(\frac{1}{2})!=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ and since $\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}\div2$ then: 
$$\begin{align}
  (\frac{1}{4})!=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\div2= \\
  \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}
\end{align}$$
Is my assumption correct? If not, what is the true answer?

By the way, I asked this question just because I am curious.

Comment: Soo... $\left(\frac{x}2\right)!=\frac12\cdot x!$, you think? As in, $4!=24$ and $2!=2$ hence $2=\frac12\cdot24$... For a more coherent approach, please see WP on the Gamma function.

Comment: Short answer: we don't know if $(1/4)!$ can be expressed using other known constants, and it is believed to not be so. (unless you want to use special functions)

Comment: it is $$\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect.  That is not how the factorial nor the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) behave.  Take for example $4!$.  Since $2=4\div2$, you seem to think that $2!=4!/2$, but a quick check says this is wrong.

Thanks to [expressions for values of the gamma function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403510v1.pdf) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function#General_rational_arguments), it is known that

$$(1/4)!=\Gamma(5/4)=\frac12\pi^{1/4}K\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^{1/2}\approx0.90640247705$$

where $K(x)$ is the elliptic $K$ function ([complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind)).

In general, for non-integer $x$, we usually extend the factorial as follows:

$$x!=\int_0^\infty t^xe^{-t}\ dt$$

for $x>-1$.  Other forms may be given in the first link, and for your specific problem, many forms are given in the [Wikipdia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function#General_rational_arguments).

Comment: Actually, it's $\Gamma(5/4)$.

Comment: If anything, that formula is probably the closest analogue to the $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ formula: note that it has $\pi$ in it as a factor but now the exponent $\frac{1}{2}$ has become $\frac{1}{4}$, in line with the input to the gamma function. It's just now that the additional factor that comes in is more interesting; richer.

Answer (score 0):

**[From here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function)**:

We have $$(1/4)! =\Gamma (5/4) =\Gamma (1/4)\frac {(4 (1)-3)!!!!}{4^1} =\Gamma (1/4)\frac {1}{4} \approx 0.90640$$

Also in general for any $x$, $$(x)! \neq \frac {(2x)!}{2} $$ Hope it helps.